# Unable to be connected to Quickbooks through Intuit App Centre | Playground

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

Does this link work?

https://appcenter.intuit.com/Playground/OAuth/IA

I am trying to get my QB online token secret required for working with a ruby gem. I have a valid QB account and I have entered my app's consumer key & secret. All I am trying to do is follow the instructions required to get the example app working from 
https://github.com/minimul/qbo_api

Every time I click on the Connect to Quickbooks button, I just get an error message.

> Oops! An error has occurred.
>
> Please close this window and try again.
>
> Error Code: no_access_to_this_field
>   Message: Team Intuit IA Application not allowed to get access to QuickBooks

I have changed the urls in my app and I still cannot get past the error message. I am at a loss since this seems to be a very basic step to start working with the gem. Please tell me the newbie mistake I am making.

Is there any other SDK I need to install? I do not have a Desktop version...just the online version.

Comment: Did you enter a Consumer Key and Secret before submitting?

Comment: Yes, I have entered both. I tried it after logging in with my account and without logging in with my account. Neither seems to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if anyone here happens to not figure out this answer already, its because I set the "Access Token Duration:" option on the Intuit Playground to 120 seconds...the default option.

I changed it to 1200 seconds by mistake, and the login works just fine now! I don't understand why that works, so if someone could answer that I could understand it better!

Thanks @William Lorfing

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you are using the playground to generate Oauth tokens for either QuickBooks or Payments access and you are not setting the correct data source.

See the answer here: https://intuitdeveloper.lc.intuit.com/questions/1247785

regards
Jarred